# Why does the tag's tool tip remain open once the mouse has crossed over it?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, stack-exchange, tooltips

Whenever my mouse moves over a tag its tool tip opens and doesn't close itself until I go over that tool tip again. Here is a screen shot of the tag information staying on the screen:

[image: Mouse is on top of page].

I'm using Google Chrome Version 43.0.2357.134 m on Windows 8.1.

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions
2. Just go slow over any tag and suddenly move away.
3. Now when your mouse pointer is no longer over the tag still the tool tip is visible

Comment: is it because of the changes I believe stack-overflow with a new look n feel?

Comment: Can you clear your browser's cache? I can't reproduce it on Chrome / Win 8.1

Comment: Ok I ll do a min please

Comment: still issue is there, it is like when I am reading a post and my mouse is going slowly over the tag so that it opens the tool tip and it remains open in questions tab. Screen shot is uploaded please check.

Comment: Same thing happens from time to time with Firefox 39, Win7.

Comment: There are a couple of things not loading properly, for you. (As you can tell from the missing images)... That might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I've also seen this intermittently on Chrome 42, Windows 7.  I haven't figured out how to reproduce this.

Comment: Chrome Version 44.0.2403.107 m, Window 7...Working fine too. Just the cache issue, I feel.  Remove Cache , Close All browser, should work

Comment: I've had this issue to, for me it comes and goes. I had a couple videos of the phenomenon but would have to look for them.

Comment: Could not replicate (Chrome 44.0.2403.125 m on Windows 7).

Comment: I've managed to replicate it once using the steps... but it doesn't seem to be consistent as I can't do so again!

Comment: Ok any solutions?

Comment: No, of course not - how could we possibly solve a problem that we can't replicate and therefore cannot understand?!

Comment: he said replicated once.

Comment: *Just go slow over any tag and suddenly move away.* Maybe your machine is busy enough that the `mouseout` event got dropped on the floor, although I would find that hard to believe. Anyway, if that's the only way you can reproduce the problem, then I see a simple solution: if it hurts when you do that, don't do that.

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh yes - **once**. Note that repeating the steps doesn't reproduce it again... so I've no idea what I did any differently the other 49 times I tried... (wasn't going to spend much longer than that trying it!)

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestions anyways.

Comment: Cannot repo Windows 7 pro 64 bit Chrome v44.0.2403.125

Comment: Ahh... one thing I can do though... is if you hover over one tag and move to hover over the tag next to it *just* before the tooltip expands, it'll still expand/close the original tooltip before expanding the new one. Once it didn't actually expand the new tab... but I can't reproduce that now either...

Comment: I've seen the same type of thing (can't tell if it is exactly the same thing) on-and-off for a considerable period of time. When it happens, I can't reproduce it. If I "watch for it", it doesn't happen. It will then happen again, 6-8 weeks later. That's with Firefox (up-to-date) and Ubuntu (14.04LTS). I'd say I've had it for at least a year, quite possibly longer. These days I have more trouble accidentally opening the tooltip whilst trying to select my favourite tags in the dropdown on the new navigation, but that's another story.

Comment: @JonClements I found that I can reproduce it by mousing over a tag, and then **immediately before** the tag description opens (around a second or so), move your mouse away quickly. (So your mouse should be away from the tag even *before* the description box opens up.) This will end up with the box open, and your mouse away from the tag. The only way to close the description at this point is to mouse over the tag again, and then mouse away.

Comment: @Jashaszun yes correct thats what is happening.