# I don't understand why they have flagged my post to close the issue without solving my problem

Tags: discussion, support

I never understand why everybody wants to close an issue without solving the problem. If they don't have the solution, they should not visit question and flag it.

[Why does the tag's tool tip remain open once the mouse has crossed over it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300368/why-the-tool-tip-of-tag-always-remains-open-once-mouse-cross-over-it)
was never solved and, as I can see, there are many other people coming out with the same problem in comments. Isn't it Stack Exchange's duty to help us out, rather than closing our issue because of others who don't even understand the issue?

Comment: Please don't roll back legitimate edits. *"If they don't have the solution, they should not visit question and flag it"* - that doesn't really make sense, whyever not? In general, you don't need to be able to solve a problem to recognise whether or not it makes an appropriate question. In this case, without being able to actually reliably reproduce the issue, how can anyone help?

Comment: ya I got it what actually make sense here.

Comment: so atleast they should not flag to close it. If I am facing an issue that's why I have raised it.

Comment: *"they should not flag to close it"* - why not? It should be put on hold until **you edit it** to provide enough information to make it answerable. When you're talking about a time-sensitive issue, a static screenshot doesn't help at all - provide steps to allow others to test and reproduce the problem.

Comment: That too I had given

Comment: ...where? *"whenever my mouse moves over a tag its tool tip opens and doesn't close itself until I go over that tool tip again"*? That is so vague as to be almost completely unhelpful. Think about what information **you would want** if someone was reporting a similar issue to you - for example, details of browser and OS versions, where exactly the pointer is and for how long, etc.

Comment: Your premise "people who close my question don't understand it" is false.

Comment: I think then those who have the same issue, they got me very well with same verses in question

Comment: Those who have the same problem, maybe. But you want to write your question for those who can actually answer.

Comment: `Isn't it Stack Exchange's duty to help us out` - not, it is not, helping people is a side effect of building a repository of knowledge for everyone. It is **your** "duty" to write questions to the site's standards.

Answer (score 8):

As was stated in the close reason this is something that can't be reproduced.  It might help if you edit you previous question to detail what OS and browser you are using.  You could also add the steps you take to get it to happen.  does it only happen before X happens or no matter what this happens.